# npm install dtrace-provider error: NOT FOUND make

Tags: node.js

I got error when i install dtrace-provider on my labtop. 
My environment is windows 10 sub linux system on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and i am using zsh.
Dose anyone know how to fix this?

I have been run as administrator for this Windows Terminal(Preview) version.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no prebuild binary provided for the platform + node version combo, it retreats back to building from source with `node-gyp`, which then throws an error because `make` binary is not found. make is required for building from source from [what the source looks like](https://github.com/chrisa/node-dtrace-provider)

solution: install make and all the requirements for this lib

https://github.com/chrisa/node-dtrace-provider#troubleshooting-build-issues

Comment: Thanks you. 
**sudo apt-get install build-essential**
works like a charm